# Elastic search results starts a new search after a space

Tags: android, elasticsearch

Look at the search results below. When I search maggi i get my desired result. After that i give a space the search result disappears and comes back after 3 letters. And it starts a complete new search after a space bar.

I am relatively new to Elastic search please help me fix it. I want it to display the result even when i give a space and should not start a new search after space.

I am using the following code.

```
HashMap<String, String> queryMap = new HashMap<>();
                queryMap.put("q", "Products:" + et_search.getText() + "");

                AndroidNetworking.get("host")
                        .addQueryParameter(queryMap)
                        .build().getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener());
```

[image]

This is how i am indexing the file.

```
input{
    file{
    path => "/Users/apple/Desktop/data/masterdbx.csv"
    start_position =>"beginning"

    }
}
filter{
    csv{
    separator => ","
    columns => ["Index", "Category", "Scat", "Sscat", "Products", "Measure", "Price", "Description", "Gst"]
    }
    mutate{convert => ["Index", "float"] }
    mutate{convert => ["Price", "float"] }
    mutate{convert => ["Gst", "float"] }

}
output{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => "host"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "pass"
        index => "masterdb"
        }

}
```

Comment: can you provide your index schema? what is datatype and configuration for "Products" fields

Comment: @SanjayKanani, I have added the config file in the question

Comment: Products are string datatype

Comment: have you try phrase match  query as it will match entire phrase that you have entered

Comment: @SanjayKanani where to add  match_phrase in the query above? any help with that?

Comment: have tried this one  "Products:\"" + et_search.getText() + "\"")

Comment: can you provide me your request body that you are currently using to search for auto-complete ?

Comment: i think it has nothing to do with elasticsearch but instead with the way the android app send a request to the es server. Could you check the content of the et_search.getText() ?